# Regular Expressions: Reducing duplication

Tags: regex

Is there a way to simplify an expression such as this

```
([0-9]||[A-Z])([0-9]||[A-Z])([0-9]||[A-Z])([0-9]||[A-Z])([0-9]||[A-Z])([0-9]||[A-Z])
```

to something like `{([0-9]||[A-Z]) = B } BBBBBB` Where B represents a duplication of a sub expression.

I'm coding in labVIEW but I'm interested in a solution that is language independent.

Comment: By "simplify" you probably mean make more readable. But the (correct) solution of adding {x} is syntactical sugar that will be re-evaluated as ([0-9]||[A-Z])([0-9]||[A-Z])([0-9]||[A-Z])([0-9]||[A-Z])([0-9]||[A-Z])([0-9]||[A-Z]) by the regex engine, which generates a performance hit.

Comment: So are you saying in terms of performance the longer expression, in this case, will be faster? I guess that's similar to inlining functions.

Comment: Precisely... Then again regex and readable in the same sentence..... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:  `([0-9]||[A-Z]){6}`

You can use `{x}` to designate the number of times you want it to show up.  `{6}` means the pattern 6 times.  You can use `{1,6}` to mean 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 times.

One thing I like to have printed up next to my desk if I'm using Regular Expressions is this:

[Regular Expression Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/)

It has saved me a number of times on syntax and such.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can just:

```
([0-9]||[A-Z]){6}
```

The 6 refers to the number of items you'll accept.  You can also:

```
([0-9]||[A-Z]){3,6}
```

Which would mean accept between 3 and 6 of these...

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the number of times a particular regex pattern would repeat using `.`,`*`,`+`,`?` or `{}` quantifiers

```
.->match only 1 time
*->0 to many times
+->1 to many times
?->0 or 1 time
{}->Exact matches..For example:{1}->1 times {1,8}->1 to 8 times
```

In your case it should be

```
([0-9]||[A-Z]){6}
```

**NOTE** (In case you want **EXACT** duplicates)

if you want to capture the same pattern..then you would have to use the reference to the previously captured group

So,

with the below regex

```
(hello) \1
```

you can match `hello hello`

So,in your case if you want the exact duplicate to repeat 6 times,you can do this

```
([0-9]||[A-Z])\1{5}
```